# Error 500 вместо error 404

Tags: python, django

Приветствую! При установке debug = False вместо 404 ошибки генерится 500. Существующие страницы сайта работают как надо. django 1.11.

Если запускаю сайт на локалке то в консоли ошибка:

```
File "/home/lepiloff/Env/protrack/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/templatetags/cache.py", line 83, in do_cache
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("'%r' tag requires at least 2 arguments." % tokens[0])
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: ''cache'' tag requires at least 2 arguments.
```

Предположил, что проблема может быть в использовании тега `*{% load cache %}*` в шаблоне, через который организовано кэширование. Убрал все что содержит cache, результат не изменился.

На что еще обратил внимание, при загрузке существующей страницы на локалке сервер отдает  `“GET / HTTP/1.1” 200 8591`, но при этом страница в браузере очень долго грузится и в консоли начинают сыпаться те же 500, что и при запросе несуществующей страницы. На рабочем сервере страницы загружаются быстро.

В общем я в замешательстве, что делать дальше.

Comment: Нашли причину? Столкнулся с такой же

Comment: Дальше надо [настроить логирование](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/) для получения подробного текста ошибки, в котором будет написано, какая именно ошибка произошла и где.

Comment: Так с помощью логгирования я и получаю сообщение об ошибке на почту админа.

Comment: Ситуация не однозначная, проблема у меня почти исчезла. Почему почти - потому что с некоторых старых url которые были в поиске но теперь удалены мне продолжают приходить сообщения с 500  ошибкой  в логе которых видно, что по несуществующему адресу заходят поисковые боты. Если формировать запрос искусственно переходя по вымышленному адресу то получаю 404. Какие меры помогли? да я честно хз, ничего конкретного я не делал кроме перезагрузки сервера и удаления memkached. Но позже memcached был переустановлен и все норм. Я склоняюсь что дело было в каком то глюке у хостера(digitalocean)